# How to display notification count on app launcher icon in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is there any way to show icon count on app launcher icon in react native?

I'm using 
"expo": "29.0.0",
"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "29.0.0"

[Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Psk.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You can try using react-native-firebase, it internally use ShortcutBadger to show notification number badges on Android:
https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/notifications/reference/Notifications

The badges in Android is changing at the moment, earlier they were supported only by launchers and since Android 8.0 they are supported also by Android:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges

So it is a little confusing to understand how react-native-firebase is supporting the badges on Android. But I managed to get them working partly, Android 9.0 device show them and older Android device (Honor8) show them when using

```
firebase.notifications().setBadge(1)
```

but not automatically when notifications are received. I quess the later one is trying to use the old launcher based badge support and either I have not done something correctly or my launcher is not supported by ShortcutBadger.
If someone have idea, please share?

If you try using react-native-firebase remember to add ShortcutBadger dependency to android/app/build.gradle and I also added setShowBadge(true) to Notification Channel created (Not sure if it was needed because it was not mentioned in documentation). Otherwise I followed the installation documentation.